# Why do I have to cast to type parameter and can't use the constrained type?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, generic-variance

Can anyone explain why I have to cast to T and why Add2 does not accept Bar as a parameter?

```
class Foo<T> where T : class, IBar
{
    void Add1(IDo<T> @do) { @do.Stuff(new Bar() as T); }

    // Add2 does not compile:
    // Argument type Bar is not assignable to parameter Type T
    void Add2(IDo<T> @do) { @do.Stuff(new Bar()); } 
}

interface IBar {}

class Bar : IBar {}

interface IDo<in T> {
    void Stuff(T bar);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may not be appropriate. For example, consider:

```
class Other : Bar {}

...

IDo<Other> do = new DoImpl<Other>();
Foo<Other> foo = new Foo<Other>();
foo.Add2(do);
```

With your current code, that would be calling `do.Add2(new Bar())`... which is clearly invalid as a `Bar` isn't an `Other`, required by `IDo<Other>.Stuff`.

Casting to `T` (or using `as`) isn't appropriate either - you can't cast a `new Bar()` to `Other`, and if you use `as` you'll just get a null reference.

Comment: `Add2` does not accept an `IBar` or one of it's subclasses. You must give it an `IDo<T>` parameter.

Comment: @mrt181: Yes, sorry - the last call was meant to be `foo.Add2(do);`. Fixed now - and hopefully this shows what's wrong.